# Laravel authenticate using phone or email and password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

My database has below structure

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('phone_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT chk_phone_or_email CHECK (email IS NOT NULL OR email IS NOT NULL);');
    }
```

Basically I have two fields `phone` and `email` that can be null but both of then cannot be null. A user can pass either their `phone` or `email` but this is passed to the backend as `username`. With this I need to attempt to login with either and if successful, return token

Below is my code

```php
    public function login(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        $usernames = ['phone', 'email'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($usernames); $i += 1){
            $credentials = ['password' => request()->get('password')];
            $credentials[$usernames[$i]] = request()->get('username');
            if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return $this->withErrorHandling(function () use ($request) {
                    return $this->convertResponse(
                        $this->server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, new Psr7Response)
                    );
                });
            }
        }


        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid username or password'
        ], 401);
    }
```

If I login with valid email and password, I am able to login but if I try to login using phone and password, I get unauthorised,

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If the `->attempt()` method relies on checking `email` in the database, using `phone` won't be compatible. You can manually find the User by `phone` or `email`, and use `Hash::check()` to validate password (supplied against hash in database), and if it matches, manually login the User. Or dig into a way to extend the `attempt()` method to allow it to work with `phone`.

Comment: `email IS NOT NULL OR email IS NOT NULL` shouldn't one of the `email`s be `phone`?

Comment: @SuperDJ thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

You can check for users with queries and login with `Auth`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-instance

for example in your controller:

```
public function login(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    $username = request()->get('username');
    $password = request()->get('password');

    $user = User::where('phone', $username)->orWhere('email', $username)->first();
    if ($user === null || !Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Invalid username or password'
        ], 401);
    }

    Auth::guard('web')->login($user);
   
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ASeddighi, this will work but it wont validate the Password grant client details, I am using passport

Comment: This part `Hash::check($password, $user->password)` check for user hashed password.

Answer (score 1):

I found below, hope it helps someone,

We can override `findForPassport` function in the users model to achieve this

```php
  public function findForPassport($identifier)
  {
    return $this->orWhere('email', $identifier)
      ->orWhere('phone', $identifier)
      ->orWhere('username', $identifier)
      ->first();
  }
}
```

See [Customizing the Username field](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#customizing-the-username-field)